# Micrsoft Logs AWS CloudWatch Logs

Tags: logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, microsoft.extensions.logging

I am currently using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to log to AWS CloudWatch , but when I look at the logs the stack trace is broken up into separate logs in cloudwatch, I read that it might be an issue with \n in the stack trace, but I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Is your app running in Lambda? and which logging framework you are using with `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, like serilog, nlog or just using default .NET Core logger?

Comment: I am running in lambda and we are just using the .net core 6 default logger

Comment: It seems a bug in Lambda, refer this - https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/1265